# Find integers of variable length, and return string version with regex

Tags: regex

Given the following text:

```
    ('ABSOLUTE', 'Absolute', 'BC', 'BC', 'V7B', 'Absolute', 45),
    ('AMEREN', 'Ameren', 'IL', 'MISO', 00000, 'AMEREN', 237),
    ('TOLEDOED', 'Toledo Edison', 'OH', 'PJM', '00000', 'FEOhio', NULL),
```

I want to find all instances of integers, and replace them with the string version.

Expected result:

```
    ('ABSOLUTE', 'Absolute', 'BC', 'BC', 'V7B', 'Absolute', '45'),
    ('AMEREN', 'Ameren', 'IL', 'MISO', '00000', 'AMEREN', '237'),
    ('TOLEDOED', 'Toledo Edison', 'OH', 'PJM', '00000', 'FEOhio', NULL),
```

So, in this case, 45 was replaced with '45', 00000 with '00000', and 237 with '237'

Do you know how to do this?

****edit**** Added a sample case that also needs to be caught:

The last one should not replace '00000' with ''00000''.

Comment: This feels like it might be an XY problem. What's the source of your bracketed expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word boundaries around your numbers with negative lookahead to disallow already quoted number and capture them in a group which would be used in back-reference in replacement:

Search pattern:

```
(\b[0-9]+\b)(?!')
```

Replacement:

```
'$1'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT2mV6/2)

Comment: Thank you. What about if there is a number that is already wrapped in apostraphes? Like '00000'?

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: Let's just assume that I will use the tool that you are using, but this is from a large insert script for a SQL Server DB. (see edit to question)